# How Can I Enable or Disable Static Modules in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got a bunch of modules installed in Apache2, enabled at compile-time.  The command `httpd -M` gives me:

```
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 ...snip...
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 ...and so on...
```

Is there a way to remove any of these static modules, or add static modules?  (Although I've got so_module loaded, so I the addition of static modules isn't so necessary.  I'd like to know how to remove static modules without recompiling the server, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to remove them without recompiling but if you do want them gone editing the build spec for your distribution will let you keep the same (presumably) known-good build settings (other than removing a ./configure flag usually) without having to go through trial and error all over again.

Building from SRPMs is usually fairly simple ([overview](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/patching_rpms.php)), rebuilding debian-based packages is a [little more complicated](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/20) but still reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If it is [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library), that means it is compiled in.  There is no easy way to add/remove them without recompiling.